# Filter NSArray with NSDictionary (nested level of object) using NSPredicate ANY and IN?

Tags: filter, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have one main array named `originalListArray` with multiple objects. Here is the example of object:

[Example.json](https://s3.amazonaws.com/arcadecrm/facility_ameniteisData.json)

I want to find that number of objects from the `originalListArray`, who have `amenity_id` matched with my filter data.

I have do this, create one predicate usign `ANY` not `self` because NSArray with NSDictionary and in that Dictionary object may have NSArray data.

This is working fine:

```
 NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY amenities.amenity_id =='1')"];
```

This is not working:

```
 NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY amenities.amenity_id in ('1','2','3')"];
```

So Single value can be filtered easily but when using `IN` oparation it crashes and the error is like this:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "ANY amenities.amenity_id in ('1','2','3')"'

Comment: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY amenities.amenity_id IN %@", @[@"1",@"2",@"3"]]`?

Comment: @Larme Yes its working. First of all, thank you for your quick response, but I didn't understand why I have to pass as an array. Because IN query we are generally pass as a comma separated value as  a string.

Comment: If you log the working predicate, you'll see that it's in fact `@"ANY amenities.amenity_id IN {'1', '2', '3'}"` (using bracelets instead of parenthesis). Not, passing it with a placeholder (%@) gives more easily changes if needed.

Comment: @Larme Ok Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to pass the array as a parameter with `%@` placeholder.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY amenities.amenity_id IN %@", @[@"1",@"2",@"3"]]
```

That way, you can create manually your array, and if you need to change it, it's easier.

If you still want it to do it manually changing the "string format":

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY amenities.amenity_id IN {'1', '2', '3'}"]
```