# NSPredicate with IN formula have not worked properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I am facing a one problem while using `NSPredicate` with `IN` formula.

One situation where I need to remove objects from the Array and that Array is a collection of Dictionary objects.

Every object has different values with same key like this.

***prevConLeadData** **Array***

```
[
{
    "assigned_name" = “set abc for test”;
    "assigned_to" = 2;
    "contact_id" = 108;
    "created_by" = 2;
    "created_date" = "2017-08-26 16:05:27";
    "first_name" = "Anthony Milgram";
},
{
    "assigned_name" = “set abc for test”;
    "assigned_to" = 2;
    "contact_id" = 541;
    "created_by" = 2;
    "created_date" = "2017-08-26 16:05:27";
    "first_name" = “GSA Gsdfgsg“;
}
,{
    "assigned_name" = “set abc for test”;
    "assigned_to" = 2;
    "contact_id" = 21;
    "created_by" = 2;
    "created_date" = "2017-08-26 16:05:27";
    "first_name" = “AASDSAS Milgram";
}
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
]
```

I want to remove objects from `prevConLeadData` array, and I found the `contact_id` from other array `deleteData` so that I am passing multiple ids using componentsJoinedByString function.

**Here is the sample code.**

```
 NSString *strIds=[deleteData componentsJoinedByString:@","];
 NSLog(@"%@",strIds); // 108
 NSArray *arrRefData=[prevConLeadData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.contact_id in (%@)",strIds]];
 [prevConLeadData removeObjectsInArray:arrRefData];
```

The issue is when I pass `strIds` who have only one value which is `108` but in predicate filter(`arrRefData`) I got the 3 objects whose contact_id is `1`,`10`,`108` so in next line remove objects from array it will removed three objects. In`arrRefData` array it should have only one object whose contact_is `108`.

If any one have faced this and find solution, please share it.

Comment: `IN %@", deleteData` instead?

Comment: Aggreed wirth @Larme, try removing brackets and `IN` instead of `in`.

Comment: For more knowledge about `NSPredicate` formats refer 
[this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html/)

Comment: @Larme Thanks. Its working like a champ. But I didn't understand the issue.

Comment: Simple, it's in the documentation. Read the part about "Aggregate Operations" and `IN` operator from the iPeter's previous link. It's `IN %@", Array` (to simplify) If you still want to do it with Strings, you can print it (now when it's working, and check it's transformed into a String predicate. It's should be the same there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544681/filter-nsarray-with-nsdictionary-nested-level-of-object-using-nspredicate-any/37545458#37545458

Comment: Thanks @Larme once again.